# How to display Current year, last year and 2 years ago sales data on line chart overlapping each other with power bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax, linechart, powerbi-desktop

I have a requirement to display the current year 2019 (Actual), the previous year 2018 and 2 years ago 2017 sales data to be displayed on one Line chart. Sales data gets generated every Sunday of the week for a total of 52 weeks in a year

Note: Data is sensitive so not in a position to share it on the forum

Report requirement, two drop downs:

1. Market selection.
2. Date selection - This date will be each Sunday of a week

Line chart :

x-axis has the date and y-axis has the market. now when any week drop down is selected (eg: 31st March 2019 then there should be three trend lines in the line chart)

1. First trend line should display details from April 2019 to March 2020
2. Second trend line should display details from April 2018 to March 2019
3. Third trend line should display details from April 2017 to March 2018

Next challenge is I am unable to achieve 2nd and 3rd trend line for previous year and 2 years ago which should be overlapping each other so, total of three trend lines in one line chart.

Another challenge I am facing is dates are not continuous across years (Eg: Jan 2018 Sunday date was 7 and Jan 2019 Sunday date was 6).

Please let me know if any additional information is required.

The image below is how I want my line chart to look like. Instead of months I want date to display:

[image: required output]

I have written a DAX which helps in displaying 1 year date range when a drop down is selected.

I want my line chart to display total three trend lines for current year,previous year and 2 years ago.

I have tried year functions to get previous year data but it does not overlap on my current trend line due to difference in date.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to have date resolution on the x-axis, if not you can use ISO-weeknumber as the x-axis and the year (or FY) as the explanation the line graph.

In your calendar table add this calculated column:

```
ISOweek = WEEKNUM([date]; 21)
```

If you need date resolution you can add two calculated columns; date+1year, and date+2years. 
Add 364 days if day of the week is the important match or add 365 if date is.

Add two new relationships from your calendar to your data table, one to date+1year and one to date+2years. these will become passive (dashed lines).

Then use the following pattern:

```
A_measure =
MAXX(
    DISTINCT(Calendar);
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(Table[Data]);
        USERELATIONSHIP(Table[date+1year]; Calendar[Date])
        // this uses the passive relationship instead of the active
    )
)
```

An then a second measure in the same way but for the third relationship.

In the line diagram use the Calendar[Date] as x-axis and then all three years will overlay.

Comment: Thank you @OscarLar i will try it out.

Yes my X- axis has Date column but it is not continuous ( Sales generated every Sunday of a month for example : March 2019 month data will have below dates 3/3/2019,3/10/2019,3/17/2019,3/ 24/2018,3/31/2019). Last year Sunday date will be obviously different so that is one problem.

Comment: Below is the DAX i used to display one trend line. what this code does in any date selection i do it will display start from next month (chosen month is Jan 19
it will display Feb 2019 - Jan 2020)

Comment: Sale = 
VAR SelectedDate = SELECTEDVALUE ( date_table[date_column])
VAR SelectedMonth =  MONTH ( SelectedDate)
VAR SelectedYear = YEAR ( SelectedDate )
VAR StartDate =  DATE ( SelectedYear, SelectedMonth +1, 1 )
VAR EndMonth =  DATE ( SelectedYear +1 , SelectedMonth, 1 )
VAR EndDate = EOMONTH(EndMonth,0)
VAR Sale = CALCULATE (  SUM (Sales_table[sale_Value_column]),
        ALL(date_table[date_column),      DATESBETWEEN(date_table[date_column,StartDate,EndDate))
RETURN
Sale

Comment: I did not understand this point (add two calculated columns; date+1year, and date+2years.)
could you please explain more?

Comment: To correlate dates from previous years with current year you need to create a column with a date offset. so you have [SalesDate]+364 if day of week is the important match. 
However, if you only have one date per week I still recommend the ISO-week alternative instead.

Comment: Thank you Oscar . yes i have one date per week which is every Sunday. I have tried ISO week no but however user wants the date( every Sunday) to display in the x-axis 52 weeks data. date is also one of the drop down. Please let me know if there is another work around for this.
If more information required kindly let me know.